# Magento quote_item and tax

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I need to add custom attributes to selected products in store. To do so I'm using Model_Price_Observer. I'm using Magento 1.7.
So far I'm able to add custom attribute but calculated price is wrong - tax is missing.

My code is (part):

```
    $quote_item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice( $customprice );
    $quote_item->setCustomPrice( $customprice );

    $quote_item->setTaxAmount($taxAmount);
    $quote_item->setBaseTaxAmount($taxAmount);
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Am I using right trigger?

Comment: Which event are you observing? And what do you want to achieve?

Comment: _sales_quote_add_item_ -

some of products have custom option that determinate its price, before adding to cart I need to get proper price. Its working, but tax is missing ;)

Comment: sorry, but the answer is no...

Comment: @arekstasiewicz, found solution?

Comment: @jafarpinjar no ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Tax cannot be added to an item as we do not yet know the customer's location in the world, and therefore cannot reasonably calculate a tax rate. I assume Magento is not saving your new tax information because of this fact. It also seems dangerous to me to add tax manually as it is always calculated on the fly via (sometimes) complex logic.

In the cart, try getting a "quick estimate" by entering in your country and postal code and see if tax is applied to the quote, and maybe try again.

Comment: Probably you are right, but why Magento is not getting those information from product when I set only base price?